# If a variable is defined previously and is waiting on a function to return a value, what is the value of that variable?

Tags: c

This is for programming in C.

Say I had the follow code in my program:

```
int fun1(int x);

int main (void) 
{
  int a = 5;
  a = fun1(10);
}

int fun1(int x) 
{

  \\Program arbitrarily ends here
  return x;
}
```

In my memory diagram what would the value of a be assuming the program terminates before fun1 is able to return a value? Would the value of a be undetermined (??) or would it be 5?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which answer do you think it is and why?

Comment: Before fun1 returns, valuse of `a` is 5.

Comment: If you compile with optimizations enabled, `a` doesn't even exist, and has no value before, during, or after the function call.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be anything other than 5? If `a` had global scope you'd expect it to be 5 right ? Why does it matter anyway? With `a` in local scope you can't see it/use it anyway...

Comment: Since the value of `a` is not observable, the "as if" rule means that the compiler can do anything it wants. There's no point asking about the value of something you cannot see. If you aren't allowed to look in the box, it doesn't matter what is in the box.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a` is already initialized to 5. Now, according to the condition, you want to know the results of that circumstance when the `fun1()` ends before it could return a value; assume the following:

```
int fun1(int x) 
{
    // return x;
}
```

Here we've supposed the function quits before returning the value.

You'll still get the output `5` before, during or after execution of the program since it returns nothing but the variable `a` is preassigned to 5 and it can't be changed to 10 unless the function returns 10 and assigns to the variable.

But remember, if you don't assign anything to `a`, then it may show an unexpected value (I got `4195638` when used `printf()` for `a`).